# HtmlAgilityPack - File Not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, html-agility-pack

I'm developing a C# ASP .NET WebPart in SharePoint Foundation.

Everything works fine, now I want to Parse a HTML Page to get all ImagePaths and save the Images on HD/Temp.

To do that I was downloading HtmlAgilityPack, current version, add reference to Project, everything looks OK, IntelliSense works fine.

But when I want to run the section where HtmlAgilityPack should be used my Browser shows me a

> FileNotFoundException - The File or Assembly could not be found.

After first searches I tried to include v1.4.0 of HtmlAgilityPack because I read that the current version in some case is not really stable. This works fine to until the point I want to use HtmlAgilityPack, the same Exception.

I also tried moving the HtmlAgilityPack direct to the Solution directory, nothing changed.

I tried to insert HtmlAgilityPack via `using` and I tried direct call e.g. `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`.

**Conclusion :**

- When I compile no error occurs, the reference is set correct.
- When I trace the `HtmlAgilityPack.dll` with ProcMon the Path is shown correct, but sometimes the Result is '`File Locked with only Readers`' but I don't know enough about ProcMon to Know what this means or if this is critical. It couldn't have something to do with File Permissions because if I check the DLL the permissions are all given.

Comment: Are you running the executable from a different location to where you built your project... If so, the HTMLAgility Pack.dll file needs to be present in the root folder. If you arent doing this, try putting the .DLL file in the bin folder where the exe is stored?

Comment: Try setting the `Copy local` to `true` for the HtmlAgilityPack reference.

Comment: You are using the .NET 2 version of HAP correct? Because SP is .NET 3.5

Comment: Which version of Sharepoint working with? This sounds more like a Sharepoint issue than a HAP issue.

Comment: @Derek - As i wrote above i tried moving the dll direct to the root and also tried moving to the bin folder - nothing happened

Comment: @Nacereddine - is already set

Comment: @Stephen - I tried with direct loading in VS2010 over NuGet, didn't work, i tried downloading the binaries of the newest Version of HAP and setting the reference manually to the .Net 4 Version after this is failing i deleted the old files and reference and set it manually to the .NET 2 Version of actual HAP, after unsucessful testing if was downloading the v1.4.0 binaries of HAP, cleaning my solution, and set a reference to that HAP dll, there's just one, didn't work at all

Comment: @David Heise - As i wrote i use Sharepoint Foundation the actual and at the moment the only version is 2010. I developed some other Projects in which i use, in some cases, added references and this always works(sometimes even very good) - so for me this sounds more like a HAP problem, but if i'll find the time maybe i'll build a Quick & Dirty Forms Solution to test if it works there

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but i had a similar problem with a CMS using an old version when I wanted a custom version. Can you use a binding redirect to make any third party dependencies use the same versions?        <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="HtmlAgilityPack" publicKeyToken="bd319b19eaf3b43a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Have you tried putting the HtmlAgilityPack dll in the GAC? If you are deploying this functionality via a SharePoint Solution with the gacdeployment switch then then the worker process won't load dlls from bin.

Answer (score 0):

I used HTML agility with this combination and it worked perfectly for me.
Please try to check below and confirm.

- Version of the DLL downloaded should support your solution.
- Make sure to place a copy in GAC.